# How can i certify the connexion to my rabbitmq server on windows ?

Tags: windows, ssl, rabbitmq, lets-encrypt

I want to securise my rabbitmq server. 
This one is on VPS server ..

It seems like i need three file to do that

> ```
> [
> {rabbit, [
>    {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
>    {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"/path/to/testca/ca_certificate_bundle.pem"},
>                   {certfile,"/path/to/server/certificate.pem"},
>                   {keyfile,"/path/to/server/private_key.pem"},
>                   {verify, verify_peer},
>                   {fail_if_no_peer_cert, true}]}
>  ]}
> ].
> ```

But when i'm trying to generate certificate with, for exemple "certify the web" I'm only getting one pem files...I think that is te certfile... 
I'm on windows server 2016...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Let's Encrypt it should give you the ability to download the certificate of the authority that signed your server cert, or that may be part of the `.pem` file you received. If there are multiple `BEGIN` sections to that file one of them will be the public part of the signing cert. Using the `openssl x509` command to print the file can tell you a lot:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in cert.pem
```

You should read the following documents:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html

https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html

This project includes `openssl` configuration and commands you can run to generate your own certificates:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#automated-certificate-generation

On Windows you would have to use MinGW but it should work.

Comment: I only have one begin section when i'm generate certificates ... :/ I will try with openssl ...